# Sharepoint 2013 document set homepage get documents with Rest API

Tags: angularjs, sharepoint-2013

Document Set Homepage:

[image: 1]

I am using Angularjs and REST API to retrieve the documents on my SharePoint 2013 document set homepage for additional functionaity. The below code works if I provide the list and folder name ('AD%20Letters/Liquidity%20Risk%20Management'), but I have more then one document set folder and need to get the List and folder names dynamically  ('"+ListName/FolderName+"') for each document set folder so it displays on the Document Set Home with the documents and other metadata. Attaching a screenshot of how the Document set homepage appears with the below code but only for the Liquidity Risk Management folder that I provide the names for. Any suggestions.

```
<script type="text/javascript">   
                var myAngApp = angular.module('SharePointAngApp', []);  
            myAngApp.controller('spCustomerController', function ($scope, $http) {  
                $http({  
                    method: 'GET',  
                    url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/getfolderbyserverrelativeurl('AD%20Letters/Liquidity%20Risk%20Management')/files?$expand=ListItemAllFields/FieldValuesAsText
                }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {  
                    $scope.customers = data.d.results;  
                }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {  
            });  
            });    
</script>  

        <h1> Policy Documents</h1>  

        <div ng-app="SharePointAngApp" class="row">  
            <div ng-controller="spCustomerController" class="span10">  
                <table class="table table-condensed table-hover">  
                    <tr>  
                        <th>ID</th>  
                        <th>File Type</th>
                        <th>Title</th>
                        <th>Project Phases</th> 
                        <th>Due Date for Comments</th>  
                        <th>Policy Type</th>   
                        <th>Author</th>    
                    </tr>  
                    <tr ng-repeat="customer in customers | orderBy:'ListItemAllFields.Development_x0020_Stage'">  
                        <td>{{customer.ListItemAllFields.ID}}</td>    
                        <td class="{{customer.ListItemAllFields.FieldValuesAsText.File_x005f_x0020_x005f_Type}}"></td>
                        <td><a href="{{customer.ServerRelativeUrl}}">{{customer.Name}}</a></td>                   
                        <td>{{customer.ListItemAllFields.Development_x0020_Stage}}</td> 
                        <td>{{customer.ListItemAllFields.FieldValuesAsText.Date_x005f_x0020_x005f_for_x005f_x0020_x005f_Review}} </td>
                        <td>{{customer.ListItemAllFields.Type_x0020_of_x0020_Letter}}</td>  
                        <td>{{customer.ListItemAllFields.FieldValuesAsText.Author}} </td>  
                     </tr>  
                </table>  
            </div>  
        </div>
```

Comment: Your code can get some help with formatting.  Would be better readable for us.  Thanks.

Comment: Fixed the code formatting..thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe you'd like to make parallel ajax calls and combine all the results?

```
var myAngApp = angular.module('SharePointAngApp', []);  
myAngApp.controller('spCustomerController', function ($scope, $http) {  
    $q.all({
        liquidityRiskManagement: $http({  
             method: 'GET',  
             url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/getfolderbyserverrelativeurl('AD%20Letters/Liquidity%20Risk%20Management')/files?$expand=ListItemAllFields/FieldValuesAsText"
                                       }),
        anotherList: $http({  
            method: 'GET',  
            url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/getfolderbyserverrelativeurl('AD%20Letters/Another%20List%')/files?$expand=ListItemAllFields/FieldValuesAsText"
                           })
        }).then(function(results) {
               var riskResult = results.liquidityRiskManagement.data;
               var anotherResult = results.anotherList.data;
               // You can combine/format data here
    });
});
```

EDIT: a good answer on parallel ajax calls: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24871403/6479268

Comment: This might work if I knew how many project folders were created under each Documents Set. In my case project folders are created as needed so I need a way to pass the list and folder name into the REST call /_api/web/getfolderbyserverrelativeurl('List/Folder')/files?$expand=ListItemAllFields/FieldValuesAsText.

Comment: I know SharePoint has the GetUrlKeyValue function ex( var listGuid = GetUrlKeyValue("List");    var itemId = GetUrlKeyValue("ID")) that would get the list and ID. I was hoping I could do something similar with Javascript to populate the /_api/web/getfolderbyserverrelativeurl('List/Folder') so its pulling the list and foldername for each project folder under the document set and display those documents on the document set homepage based on which project was selected. Right now I am hard coding the folder name (AD%20Letters/Liquidity%20Risk%20Management).

Comment: Who not simply set a custom content type and target that with one query then? Often complications with the implementation can be solved by structuring the Lists better.

Answer (score 0):

I figured how to do this for those who might benefit. I used the available SharePoint `GetUrlKeyValue` and grabbed the `RootFolder` which is available as a querystring for each document set (`var listFolder = GetUrlKeyValue("RootFolder");`)

```
var listFolder = GetUrlKeyValue("RootFolder");
var url = "/_api/web/getfolderbyserverrelativeurl('"+listFolder+"')/files?$expand=ListItemAllFields/FieldValuesAsText"
```

Now I get documents/files for each docset folder on the Docset Homepage.